# How to setRequiredLevel specific control or attribute?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, getattribute

My mission is to check if a control is visible and if it is then to set it as required.
On my form I have the same field twice (in different sections) so to check my control visibility I use this code:

```
if(Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("tab1").sections.get("section").controls.get("attrname").getVisible()) //works
{
              Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("tab1").sections.get("section").controls.get("attrname").setRequiredLevel("required"); //doesn't work - error
              Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("tab1").sections.get("section").controls.get("attrname").getAttribute("attrname").setRequiredLevel("required");  //doesn't work - error
}
```

How do I set the required level in this case?

Comment: You got two answers, one to explain why the error is coming, another for best practice. Upvote/accept the answer which helped you & close the thread.

Answer (score 3):

Don't take dependencies in your code on the tab/section names. Use the shortcut method for getting the attribute

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_attributename");
```

And if you need to call a method on a control of the attribute use the controls array to loop through the all of the controls:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_attributename").controls
```

Then your code will always work, as long as the attribute is somewhere on the form, and the control will work even if there is one control in the header, one in the Business Process Flow, and multiple controls in each section.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the same attribute in multiple different sections, you will get a new name appended by sequence number. For ex. `attrname`, `attrname1`, `attrname2` and so on.

So you have to get the right attribute to set the property when you go through the tab/section. Anyway the result will be, all the attribute copies will get the property set.

```
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("tab1").sections.get("section2").controls.get("new_rep1").getAttribute("new_rep1").setRequiredLevel("required");
```

**Result**:

> [image]